# Как из Docker-контейнера послать команду на перезагрузку другого контейнера?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть три контейнера: `PHP`, `MariaDB` и `JAVA-Spring` 
на `PHP` висит основной сайт, `JAVA` подключается к базе сайта и делает некоторые тяжелые операции с обработкой файлов.
Также у `JAVA-Spring` есть `REST-api` который отдает статус сервера (работает или нет)

Есть ли возможность из кода `PHP/других команд` (неважно как), отправить контейнер `JAVA-Spring` в перезагрузку, если вдруг сервис остановился? т.е. получается управлять другим контейнером из соседнего контейнера. Либо отправить команду на хост-машину.
По сути да - ведь есть главный "управляющий" `portainer.io`, который сам работает из контейнера. И мне нужно сделать тоже самое.

Comment: Вы, конечно, можете управлять контейнером из контейнера, но у меня больше вопрос, почему бы не делать это функционалом докера через `HEALTHCHECK `(https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck), а при запуске задать restart policy `docker run -d --restart unless-stopped`(https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy) это уберет необходимость писать и поддерживать +1 контейнер

Comment: @PZBird, через `HEALTHCHECK` не получится по одной большой причине: сам контейнер не падает. падает конкретный блок сервиса, при этом сам сервис работает. А если еще точнее: хостовая система подключает `DFS-шару` к хосту, далее она прокинута `volume` в два других. PHP (контейнер1) ищет директории и PDF-файлы, добавляет в БД. JAVA(контейнер2) проверяет БД и если есть файлы с количеством страниц = 0, то дергает файлы, проверяя кол-во страниц и обновляет записи.

Comment: @PZBird Есть нюанс: сначала должно быть мониторование на хост, и потом запуск контейнера. В противном случае директория пустая. (`mount-cifs` может отработать как до запуска контейнера, так и после) И если она пустая, JAVA-шедулер останавливается. Далее проверяем, если монтирование было после запуска контейнера, то просто в PHP нажимаем кнопочку рестарта Spring-контейнера. Ну либо как-то реализовать зависимость: пока `mount-cifs` не отработает, контейнеры не запускать. Но ответа на этот вопрос не нашел совершенно. Поэтому на текущий момент, проще перезагрузить.

Answer (score 0):

Можно прокинуть сокет докера внутрь контейнера и далее использовать [docker engine api](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerRestart).

Пример запроса:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -X POST http://localhost/v1.41/containers/1c6594faf5/restart
```